# Herarchical class classifier with default parent class labelling

Tags: multi-class, multilabel

I have a hierarchy of classes for which I need to train a classifier which will assign the lowest level class in the hierarchy  and default to an upper level class , is this possible to do with scikit out of the box or should I collapse the class labels as the entire path in the hierarchy and use it as the label? The task is sequence prediction task very similar to POS tagging and with  hierarchical POS tags.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into modeling this problem as an [hierarchical Bayesian model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_hierarchical_modeling) and implementing it with [pymc3](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/getting_started/) (out of the box).

After sampling the posterior distribution, you could use a threshold on the higher levels, to default to a higher level class.

Comment: can you give a concrete example for this

Comment: No, because I don't know anything about your data

Comment: The task is sequence prediction task very similar to POS tagging and with  hierarchical POS tags.